# Users who receive email/bot notifications considered "active"?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I consider a user to be "active" whenever they sign into my web app. I recently introduced daily emails & bot notifications that include summarized user data.

In theory, I think the notifications contain enough useful information that some users are satisfied and don't need to log into the app as frequently.

I think this is a win for my users in terms of convenience, but throws a wrench in my "active users" metric. Users that were previously signing in once/twice a week are now signing in less, but are happy with receiving daily notifications.

I'm trying to figure out how to accurately compensate my "active users" metric for this change. Should I classify users who receive notifications as "active"?

Comment: That is completely up to you.

Comment: Whilst it might be "up to you" it could still be an important metric to clarify -  what is generally considered an "active user"? If the site is being monetised/seeking sponsorship then the number of "active users" might be a required metric. Would a potential "sponsor" consider a user that only receives email notifications "active"? If not then the potential value of the site could be reduced. (I thought I'd seen a question like this asked before??)

Comment: Do you track email opens?   If so it might be reasonable to mark users as active when they read the email.

Comment: @w3dk It's only for internal use, for monitoring the general metric of "how many users are using the app?"